# JavaScript Bookmarklet: Infinite loop to perform a function, then on page load, execute the function again

Tags: javascript, function, loops, bookmarklet, infinite

How would I go about implementing this as a bookmarklet?

This is the function that I have:

```
javascript: function tr_f() { 
  var followlinks = []; 
  for (var i=0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
        if (document.links[i].getAttribute("class")=="follow"){
              followlinks[followlinks.length] = document.links[i];
        }
  } 
  for (var i=0; i<followlinks.length; i++) {
        var rrr=followlinks[i].onclick();
  } 
} tr_f();
```

I want to modify this code to perform the function, then refresh the page, wait a few seconds, and execute the function again - in an infinite loop.

Alternatively, in fact a better method, would be to refresh the page once the bookmarklet has been clicked, execute the function on page load, and then do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it as a bookmarklet, all code is lost after the page reloads and then loaded again but your bookmarklet isn't part of the page so you have to manually execute it again which means you are back to square one.

However, what are you trying to do anyway? You could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) so your script doesn't have to start from scratch every time it is ran.

Comment: I'm trying to automatically click all instances of a button on a webpage - in this instance a "follow" button. The webpage in question fetches new unclicked instances on page reload. How would I implement localStorage?

Comment: @Schwing If you must refresh the page to get updates then localStorage doesn't help, you'd need to fetch the updates from the script (using AJAX, JSONP, or whatever they have) so you don't have to reload to get them. Alternatively you could just use greasemonkey, it executes the bookmarklet on every pageload automatically

Comment: Seems a bit complicated. I'm not sure I'd be able to fetch that information - it isn't exactly accessible to the public (there's no API)

Comment: @Schwing, then if you are using firefox or chrome, the greasemonkey is an extension that would easily allow you do this.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a browser extension for this purpose opposed to a bookmarklet. I'd rather implement this standalone - i.e. my own extension, without the need for greasemonkey

Comment: @Schwing, then the extension can execute the script on every pageload. No need for GM if you are doing an extension. But without any extension it's not possible.

Comment: so, back to the original question, only outside of the context of a bookmarklet, how would I do this in an infinite loop?

Comment: @Schwing, just do `document.location.reload()` at the end of the function.. maybe with a timer so it doesn't run too often: `window.setTimeout( function(){document.location.reload();}, 5000 );`

Comment: Would that execute infinitely?

Comment: @Schwing, yes every time the page loads the script would be executed by your extension, and it would reload the page after 5 seconds and then this loop will continue as long as the extension is enabled and the page is open.

Comment: Hey again, I've added the timer to the refresh, but it only clicks follow once and then refreshes after 5 seconds. If I remove the timer, it doesn't click anything at all. Would it be possible to perform the refresh only after all instances of the follow button on the page has been clicked?